# Nodejs SDK - Merge dialog + intents

Tags: node.js, android-intent, dialog, botframework

Is there any way I can merge the dialog with intent so that I do not need to have the redundant code snippet?

```
 bot.dialog('whats-your-name', require('./dialogs/whats-your-name'))    
 intents.matches('whats-your-name', require('./dialogs/whats-your-name'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could plug your instantiated IntentDialog into your root dialog (`"/"`) and have the IntentDialog handle all of the routing:

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });
bot.dialog("/", intents);
```

Or you could forgo the the IntentDialog and instead plug your recognizers into the bot-level like so:

```
bot.recognizer(recognizer);
bot.dialog("/", [ ... ]);

bot.dialog("luisIntentA", [ ... ])
   .triggerAction({
     matches: "luisIntentA"
   });
```

I recommend the latter approach as this affords more control over routing intents and switching between dialogs.